# How to enable my code to return true when n1 is equal to n2?

Tags: java

My questions&problems: 1.When n1==n2==5 and I run this program,it shows:"n1 is equal to n2? false",which is problematic,how could I fix it?

```
                                  1st part of the code
    class MyInteger {
        int value;
        public MyInteger(int value){
            
        }
        public static int get(int value) {
            return value;
        }
         public static char[] parseInt(char[]chars) {
            //converting array of numeric numbers to int numbers
            return MyInteger.parseInt(chars);
        }
          public void equals(int value) {
        }
    }
```

```
                          2nd part (test part) of the code
     public class Test {
              public static void main(String[] args) {
                MyInteger n1 = new MyInteger(5);
            har[] chars = {'3', '5', '3', '9'};
                System.out.println(MyInteger.parseInt(chars));
                System.out.println(parseInt2());
                    MyInteger n2 = new MyInteger(5);
                }
```

Comment: override `boolean equals(Object other)` method

Comment: Also, change your `public static char[] parseInt(char[]chars)` method, which is currently calling itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have not overwritten [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method. Method expects Object as input argument, not a primitive int.

Your method will not be used in Sets,Maps and other structures that are using equals and hashCode. It's just another object method.

Your Equals [method should look](https://www.sitepoint.com/implement-javas-equals-method-correctly/) like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // self check
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    // null check
    if (o == null)
        return false;

    // [TIP] If you want to compare to an Integer, you can do it here

    // type check and cast
    if (getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    MyInteger other = (MyInteger) o;
    // field comparison
    return this.value == other.value;
}
```

You also need to assign value:

```
 public MyInteger(int value){
    this.value = value;
 }
```

Without it all values will be equal to 0, thus making them equal to each other.

Now the output would be:

```
    MyInteger n1 = new MyInteger(1);
    MyInteger n2 = new MyInteger(2);
    MyInteger n3 = new MyInteger(2);

    System.out.println(n2.equals(n1)); // false
    System.out.println(n2.equals(n3)); // true
```

Comment: ,I have added the above code to my 1st part of the program,but the reactions this program makes are still wrong.After I run it,it displays following messages(with n1=n2=4):n1 is equal to n2? true
n1 is equal to 5? false

Comment: In your example you are not setting value.